# What is the connection between anxiety and humility in 1 Peter 5:6-7?

Tags: 1-peter

1 Peter 5:6-7 NASB

> “Therefore humble yourselves under the mighty hand of God, that He may exalt you at the proper time, casting all your anxiety on Him, because He cares for you.”
> ‭‭

How does Peter move from humbling ourselves under God to casting our anxiety on Him? What anxieties might he be referring to, and how does that connect to the need to humble ourselves before God and man (as noted earlier in the chapter)?

Answer (score 1):

Peter expressed a concern about the conflict in a church, in between the elders and the young members. He encouraged the elders '*Be shepherds of God’s flock (the young members) that is under your care, watching over them—not because you must, but because you are willing, as God wants you to be; not pursuing dishonest gain, but eager to serve; (1 Peter 5:2 NIV)*, and on the other way round, he encouraged the young members (the flock) *'In the same way, you who are younger, submit yourselves to your elders. All of you, clothe yourselves with humility toward one another' (1 Peter 5:5 NIV)*

Conflict is a consequence of insufficient trust and respect of each other, and conflict creates anxiety to both parties. When the conflict cannot be resolved, it will form a downward spiral curve that eventually dissect the coalition of the church.

Peter reminded **both of them** that *'Your enemy the devil prowls around like a roaring lion looking for someone to devour.' (vv5:8)* So do not act on their flesh but submitted to *'God mighty hand' (vv5:6)*, for God *'opposes the proud but shows favor to the humble.' (vv5:5)* In this way, their anxiety due to the conflict would be released.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Matthew 6:25-33

> “Therefore I tell you, do not worry about your life, what you will eat, or about your body, what you will wear. Is not life more than food and the body more than clothing?  Look at the birds in the sky; they do not sow or reap, they gather nothing into barns, yet your heavenly Father feeds them. Are not you more important than they?  *Can any of you by worrying add a single moment to your life-span?*  Why are you anxious about clothes? Learn from the way the wild flowers grow. They do not work or spin.  But I tell you that not even Solomon in all his splendor was clothed like one of them.  If God so clothes the grass of the field, which grows today and is thrown into the oven tomorrow, will he not much more provide for you, O you of little faith?  So do not worry and say, ‘What are we to eat?’ or ‘What are we to drink?’ or ‘What are we to wear?’  All these things the pagans seek. Your heavenly Father knows that you need them all.  But seek first the kingdom of God and his righteousness, and all these things will be given you besides.

Emphasis added.

It details why a Christian should not worry and be anxious, but it points out the necessity of it:  the Christian can not, in fact, secure what he is anxious about.  He *must* depend on God, and not himself.  This requires humility.